# how to add new object files at the start in an existing static library

Tags: linux, linker, static-libraries, archive

I have an existing static library libelab.a 
I want to add two object files obj1.o, obj2.o at the start index in libelab.a

What options with ar command should I use?

man page says that b is the modifier for this task, but I tried to use it as : 'ar rbvs libelab.a obj1.o obj2.o', but following error is given 
ar: obj1.o: File format not recognized

Comment: run following command `file ojb1.o` to check the file formats of your `ojb1.o` and `libelab.a` files.

Answer (score -1):

I realize that I was using the wrong syntax.

man page for ar command says following about modifier b :

```
   b   Add new files before an existing member of the archive.  If you use the modifier b, the name of an existing archive member must be present as the relpos argument, before the archive specification.
```

So to use the b option, I have to specify existing object file name in library, before which I want theses 2 new objects to be added.

For example, if old.o was an existing object file in library, following would be the right syntax :

```
ar rbvs old.o libelab.a obj1.o obj2.o
```